# What are the appendeges behind a crane fly's wings?

Tags: entomology, terminology, diptera

I noticed that crane flies have strange appendages behind their wings. The appendages look like a pair of antenna or a pair of vestigial wings. In the following picture I marked these appendages with arrows.

[image: crane fly]

The specimen in the picture sat on my window this morning. I looked through the [genera on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crane_fly#Genera), that is, on the images if there were any. All crane fly species seem to have these appendages.

While the appendages are clearly visible in most images I couldn't find a description of them. I've never seen anything like them and would like to know:

- What's the name of these appendages?
- What are they good for? Are they vestigial wings, antenna, or some sort of counter weight to stabilize the flight?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are the [halteres](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halteres). These structures help the flies to perceive body rotation and maintain balance.